# Is this NSString a memory leak?

Tags: ios, memory, ios7, nsstring

```
NSString *pDescText = @"blablabla";
pDescText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",skProduct.localizedDescription,formattedPrice];
```

Does this produce a memory leak when I reassign pDescText in line 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using ARC, you don't need to worry about these kinds of leaks.

If you are using MRC, you don't have a leak because:

You only need to release objects that you have a received a reference to by sending messages which contain `new` `alloc` `retain` or `copy`. In neither of these lines have you done this so you don't have an owned reference to `pDescText`. Furthermore, in the first line you are using a string literal, which is something that yo don't have to worry about memory management for.

And I have to say this `pDescText` is not a good name to use for a variable in Cocoa. We don't use hungarian notation (so the p to indicate a pointer isn't needed) and full, descriptive variable names are the norm. So instead of `pDescText` a more experienced Cocoa developer would use `descriptiveText` or even `productDescription` or `description` if that is enough for the context.

Comment: It is always nice to get a little extra gem (re: variable names) when answering a question just to help out other newbies who might be looking at this answer.

Comment: I use a little mnemonic I came up with: If it's *N* -ot *ARC*, release *NARC* ( *N* ew, *A* lloc, *R* etain, *C* opy ). If you don't see those words, don't worry about releasing

Comment: I wanted to have a tshirt that said `new & alloc & retain & copy`; just like the famous [Beatles t-shirt](http://www.experimentaljetset.nl/archive/john-paul-ringo-george)

Answer (score 0):

No, `NSString` convenience constructors return an autoreleased object.